# Как оптимизировать по размеру код на C?

Tags: c, оптимизация

Есть функция, которая выглядит примерно следующим образом:

```
static void vParseAtResponse(char *const pcAtResponse)
{
    if (!strcmp(pcAtResponse, CALL_READY)) {
        xGsmGeneralState.CallReady = TRUE;
        return;
    }

    if (!strcmp(pcAtResponse, CPAS0)) {
        if (xGsmVoiceStatus != GSM_VOICE_NOT_ESTABLISHED)
            vGsmHangUp();
        return;
    }

    ...

    if (!strncmp(pcAtResponse, CPIN_PREFIX, _strlen(CPIN_PREFIX))) {
        char *pStr = pcAtResponse;
        pStr += strlen(CPIN_PREFIX) + 1;

        if (!strcmp(pStr, READY)) {
            xGsmGeneralState.PinEntered = TRUE;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

При этом блоков вида `if (!strncmp())){}` (в которых делается сравнение строк) там где сейчас многоточие порядка десятка.

А теперь к сути вопроса. Вся программа очень немаленькая и при этом без указанной функции в скомпилированном виде весит ~90 КБ. Добавляю эту функцию только с одним упомянутым блоком - 93 КБ. Раскоментирую остальные блоки - 190 КБ!!! Подскажите, где тут узкое место?

**UPD:** Компилятор GCC (платформа AVR32). Изначально все описанное происходило с уровнем оптимизации -O2.
**UPD2** Оптимизация -Os. Макроопределения - обычные строки типа "+CPIN:", "READY","Call Ready"

Случай первый. Один блок с CALL_READY

```
800053d0 <vParseAtResponse>:
800053d0:   d4 01           pushm   lr
800053d2:   48 7b           lddpc   r11,800053ec <vParseAtResponse+0x1c>
800053d4:   f0 1f 00 07     mcall   800053f0 <vParseAtResponse+0x20>
800053d8:   c0 81           brne    800053e8 <vParseAtResponse+0x18>
800053da:   30 19           mov r9,1
800053dc:   48 68           lddpc   r8,800053f4 <vParseAtResponse+0x24>
800053de:   48 7b           lddpc   r11,800053f8 <vParseAtResponse+0x28>
800053e0:   b0 89           st.b    r8[0x0],r9
800053e2:   48 7c           lddpc   r12,800053fc <vParseAtResponse+0x2c>
800053e4:   f0 1f 00 07     mcall   80005400 <vParseAtResponse+0x30>
800053e8:   d8 02           popm    pc
800053ea:   00 00           add r0,r0
800053ec:   80 00           ld.sh   r0,r0[0x0]
800053ee:   70 c4           ld.w    r4,r8[0x30]
800053f0:   80 00           ld.sh   r0,r0[0x0]
800053f2:   63 ac           ld.w    r12,r1[0x68]
800053f4:   00 00           add r0,r0
800053f6:   13 90           ld.ub   r0,r9[0x1]
800053f8:   80 00           ld.sh   r0,r0[0x0]
800053fa:   70 d0           ld.w    r0,r8[0x34]
800053fc:   80 00           ld.sh   r0,r0[0x0]
800053fe:   70 dc           ld.w    r12,r8[0x34]
80005400:   80 00           ld.sh   r0,r0[0x0]
80005402:   50 e8           stdsp   sp[0x38],r8
```

Случай второй. 2 блока - с CALL_READY и CPIN_PREFIX:

```
800053d0 <vParseAtResponse>:
800053d0:   d4 21           pushm   r4-r7,lr
800053d2:   4a 2b           lddpc   r11,80005458 <vParseAtResponse+0x88>
800053d4:   18 96           mov r6,r12
800053d6:   f0 1f 00 22     mcall   8000545c <vParseAtResponse+0x8c>
800053da:   c0 60           breq    800053e6 <vParseAtResponse+0x16>
800053dc:   0c 9c           mov r12,r6
800053de:   30 79           mov r9,7
800053e0:   4a 0b           lddpc   r11,80005460 <vParseAtResponse+0x90>
800053e2:   30 0e           mov lr,0
800053e4:   c1 68           rjmp    80005410 <vParseAtResponse+0x40>
800053e6:   30 19           mov r9,1
800053e8:   49 f8           lddpc   r8,80005464 <vParseAtResponse+0x94>
800053ea:   4a 0b           lddpc   r11,80005468 <vParseAtResponse+0x98>
800053ec:   b0 89           st.b    r8[0x0],r9
800053ee:   4a 0c           lddpc   r12,8000546c <vParseAtResponse+0x9c>
800053f0:   f0 1f 00 20     mcall   80005470 <vParseAtResponse+0xa0>
800053f4:   d8 22           popm    r4-r7,pc
800053f6:   fc 0a 18 00     cp.b    r10,lr
800053fa:   5f 08           sreq    r8
800053fc:   fc 09 18 00     cp.b    r9,lr
80005400:   5f 09           sreq    r9
80005402:   12 48           or  r8,r9
80005404:   fc 08 18 00     cp.b    r8,lr
80005408:   c0 d1           brne    80005422 <vParseAtResponse+0x52>
8000540a:   2f fb           sub r11,-1
8000540c:   f3 d7 c0 08     bfextu  r9,r7,0x0,0x8
80005410:   19 8a           ld.ub   r10,r12[0x0]
80005412:   f2 c7 00 01     sub r7,r9,1
80005416:   2f fc           sub r12,-1
80005418:   17 88           ld.ub   r8,r11[0x0]
8000541a:   f4 08 18 00     cp.b    r8,r10
8000541e:   ce c0           breq    800053f6 <vParseAtResponse+0x26>
80005420:   d8 22           popm    r4-r7,pc
80005422:   ec c7 ff f8     sub r7,r6,-8
80005426:   49 4b           lddpc   r11,80005474 <vParseAtResponse+0xa4>
80005428:   0e 9c           mov r12,r7
8000542a:   f0 1f 00 0d     mcall   8000545c <vParseAtResponse+0x8c>
8000542e:   c0 51           brne    80005438 <vParseAtResponse+0x68>
80005430:   30 19           mov r9,1
80005432:   48 d8           lddpc   r8,80005464 <vParseAtResponse+0x94>
80005434:   b0 99           st.b    r8[0x1],r9
80005436:   d8 22           popm    r4-r7,pc
80005438:   0e 9c           mov r12,r7
8000543a:   49 0b           lddpc   r11,80005478 <vParseAtResponse+0xa8>
8000543c:   f0 1f 00 08     mcall   8000545c <vParseAtResponse+0x8c>
80005440:   c0 b1           brne    80005456 <vParseAtResponse+0x86>
80005442:   48 fb           lddpc   r11,8000547c <vParseAtResponse+0xac>
80005444:   fe 7c 1c 00     mov r12,-58368
80005448:   f0 1f 00 0e     mcall   80005480 <vParseAtResponse+0xb0>
8000544c:   48 eb           lddpc   r11,80005484 <vParseAtResponse+0xb4>
8000544e:   fe 7c 1c 00     mov r12,-58368
80005452:   f0 1f 00 0c     mcall   80005480 <vParseAtResponse+0xb0>
80005456:   d8 22           popm    r4-r7,pc
80005458:   80 00           ld.sh   r0,r0[0x0]
8000545a:   70 cc           ld.w    r12,r8[0x30]
8000545c:   80 00           ld.sh   r0,r0[0x0]
8000545e:   64 30           ld.w    r0,r2[0xc]
80005460:   80 00           ld.sh   r0,r0[0x0]
80005462:   70 c4           ld.w    r4,r8[0x30]
80005464:   00 00           add r0,r0
80005466:   13 90           ld.ub   r0,r9[0x1]
80005468:   80 00           ld.sh   r0,r0[0x0]
8000546a:   70 d8           ld.w    r8,r8[0x34]
8000546c:   80 00           ld.sh   r0,r0[0x0]
8000546e:   70 e4           ld.w    r4,r8[0x38]
80005470:   80 00           ld.sh   r0,r0[0x0]
80005472:   50 e8           stdsp   sp[0x38],r8
80005474:   80 00           ld.sh   r0,r0[0x0]
80005476:   70 f8           ld.w    r8,r8[0x3c]
80005478:   80 00           ld.sh   r0,r0[0x0]
8000547a:   71 00           ld.w    r0,r8[0x40]
8000547c:   80 00           ld.sh   r0,r0[0x0]
8000547e:   71 08           ld.w    r8,r8[0x40]
80005480:   80 00           ld.sh   r0,r0[0x0]
80005482:   21 30           sub r0,19
80005484:   00 00           add r0,r0
80005486:   12 d0           st.w    --r9,r0
```

Comment: Почему не попробовать последовательно раскоментировать ``if`` блоки и смотреть получившийся размер, попутно заглядывая в ассемблерный листинг, сгенерированный компилятором?

Comment: Можно и попробовать. Сейчас гляну

Comment: В подобных вопросах **обязательно** говорите, какие компилятор и ОС.

А так, попробуйте уровнем оптимизации у компилятора поиграться.

Вообще, по виду этих блоков, на килобайты никак не тянет. Загадка.


По поводу подобных минусов. Похоже какой-то **неадекват** завелся. Уже не первый такой минус вижу. Похоже он минусует то, что сам не понимает.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, поправил. 
Пробовал менять оптимизацию на -Os. Размер изначально (без функции) ~86 КБ. Каждый блок if(... ) + 0.3-0.4КБ. Уже лучше конечно...

Comment: @avp это не я :) честное слово :) хотя я тоже иногда неадекват :)

Comment: Ну если каждый блок if 0.3-0.4 кб, а все вместе -- 100 кб, то, возможно, следует немного пересмотреть дизайн (интересно, сколько бы такая канитель весила на форте)

Comment: @avp, следующий шаг в подобном нарциссизме - возмущаться почему *проклятые неадекваты* не голосуют ЗА :-) Минус мой, в свете последних правок можно было бы его убрать, но тогда Ваш комментарий *потеряет всякую ценность* :-) Кстати, до сих пор не ясно, что именно кодогенератор добавляет на каждое сравнение.

Comment: @karmadro4, фиг с ней, с ценностью (убирайте, он уже помог автору). Лучше объясните, чем руководствовались ?

Comment: @avp, сначала Вы :-)

> чем руководствовались ?

Уже упомянутые и поправленные конпелятор/платформа/тип оптимизации, плюс всё еще актуальные *загадочные* макроопределения. Кто знает, что там спрятано...

Comment: Тупо и нетонко.

Comment: Добавил тот желанный =) листинг. При добавлении блока - длина его растет больше чем в 2 раза((

Comment: Интересно, тот, кто пожелал листинг, знаком с архитектурой avr32? (я -- нет). И за счёт чего получается 300-400 байт? За счёт вызываемых процедур из if-блоков, которые линкер выбрасывает, если вызовы закомментарить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Комментировать больше не получается(, пишу в ответе...

[[@alexlz](/users/352/alexlz)](/users/352/alexlz) - В приведенном примере в обоих блоках никаких процедур не вызывается (кроме str**).
`_strlen` просочилась из попытки заменить ф-ции работы со строками на упрощенные самописные. Приведенный асм. листинг соответствует функциям из `strig.h`.
Вернулся к варианту со стандартными ф-ями потому как в других модулях уже они используются и подменить их на самописный вариант руки не дошли, а так они уже размер занимают. Хотя, может стоило попробовать.

**UPD** Нашел мое упущение, о котором не написал. Сейчас только заметил, что реально объем увеличивается при расском-ии блока, содержащего sprintf. Вот там-то собака и покопалась! Как раз эта зараза и получается под сотню КБ! По сути проблема решена. Всем спасибо.Надо только придумать как без нее строки парсить. А то у меня всего памяти 256КБ, а она!!! Чертяка

Comment: Ну, отлично. А я (AVR32 не знаю) просто посмотрел на адреса, обнаружил, что разница в 132 байта и решил сообщить об этом (в смысле, что эти блоки тут ни при чем).

Смотрю, а тема обновилась, Вы уже все решили !

Comment: А у неё нет возможностей усечения? Ну, например, отрубить плавающую арифметику? Или у гугла спросить? Там наворотов много, и из них, скорее всего, требуется незначительное количество. (Краем уха глянул, вроде какие-то рекомендации д. быть в stdio.h. У меня avr-libc нет)

Есть у меня avr-libc для avr8, там есть рекомендация

       -Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_min

Так оно у Вас для avr32 или нет -- не знаю

Comment: По поводу sprintf. Наверное проще всего взять исходник из GNU libc и выбросить все лишнее.